# Bulk rename files with numbers of unequal widths

Tags: bash, rename

I have files like

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
file3.txt
...
file11.txt
file12.txt
...
file100.txt
file101.txt
...
```

I'd like to rename them to have the same string width like

```
file001.txt
file002.txt
file003.txt
...
file011.txt
file012.txt
...
file100.txt
file101.txt
...
```

Is there a simple command to achieve this?
I want to avoid manual renames, e.g. using ranger bulkrename.

Comment: Is the prefix (`file`) and the suffix (`.txt`) always the same?

Comment: Yes, always the same, but more general solutions are also welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the manual pages [`rename(1)`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rename.1.html), you can see an example to do that:

```
EXAMPLES
       Given the files foo1, ..., foo9, foo10, ..., foo278, the commands

              rename foo foo00 foo?
              rename foo foo0 foo??

       will turn them into foo001, ..., foo009, foo010, ..., foo278
```

So in your case, the simple solution (in case the maximum number is 3 digit long) would be:

```
rename file file00 file?.txt
rename file file0 file??.txt
```

Before run the actual `rename` command, you can test it by adding `--no-act / -n` and `--verbose / -v` flags to see what would be the outcome:

```
$ rename -nv file file00 file?.txt
`file1.txt' -> `file001.txt'
`file2.txt' -> `file002.txt'
`file3.txt' -> `file003.txt'
$ rename -nv file file0 file??.txt
`file11.txt' -> `file011.txt'
`file12.txt' -> `file012.txt'
```

A more general solution (available since `bash` version 3.0):

```
$ for i in `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f -name 'file*.txt'`; \
  do if [[ "$i" =~ file([0-9]*).txt$ ]]; \
    then NUM=$(printf "%03d" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"); \
    echo mv --verbose $i $i ./file${NUM}.txt; \
  fi; \
done
mv --verbose ./file1.txt ./file001.txt
mv --verbose ./file2.txt ./file002.txt
mv --verbose ./file3.txt ./file003.txt
mv --verbose ./file11.txt ./file011.txt
mv --verbose ./file12.txt ./file012.txt
mv --verbose ./file100.txt ./file100.txt
mv --verbose ./file101.txt ./file101.txt
```

Remove the `echo` when you want to perform the change. It's just a simple example, you can change the prefix and suffix of the files to patterns as well in the `if` line, and use `$BASH_REMATCH` to capture those to make more complex renames. For instance:

```
$ for i in `find ./ -maxdepth 1 -type f`; \
  do if [[ "$i" =~ ^([^0-9]*)([0-9]*).txt$ ]]; \
    then NUM=$(printf "%03d" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"); \
    echo mv --verbose $i ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${NUM}.txt; \
  fi; \
done
mv --verbose ./file1.txt ./file001.txt
mv --verbose ./file2.txt ./file002.txt
mv --verbose ./file3.txt ./file003.txt
mv --verbose ./file11.txt ./file011.txt
mv --verbose ./file12.txt ./file012.txt
mv --verbose ./file100.txt ./file100.txt
mv --verbose ./file101.txt ./file101.txt
mv --verbose ./something1.txt ./something001.txt
mv --verbose ./another02.txt ./another002.txt
```

Of course in the you can modify the `printf` command to change the zero padding length from 3 to any other number.

Comment: That exactly answers my question. It would be nice to do it in a single command though, in case there are even larger numbers.

Comment: Note that there are two different versions of a `rename` command. This answer uses the syntax of the version that is part of the util-linux package. On Ubuntu, `rename` is by default a symlink to the Perl version named `prename`. The latter uses a Perl expression to control the renaming.

Answer (score 0):

To rename files with all sequences of ASCII decimal digits left-padded to a width of 3 with 0s, with `zsh`:

```
autoload -Uz zmv
zmv -n '*' '${f//(#m)<->/${(l[3][0])MATCH}}'
```

(remove `-n` for dry-run if happy with the result).

Same with perl-based `rename` implementations (sometimes called `file-rename`, `prename` or `perl-rename`):

```
rename -n 's/\d+/sprintf "%03d", $&/ge' ./*[0123456789]*
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the perl `rename` utility, which is also known as `file-rename`, `perl-rename`, or `prename`. It is not to be confused with the `rename` utility from `util-linux` which has completely different and incompatible capabilities and command-line options.  Perl rename allows you to use any arbitrarily complex perl code to rename files, but is most often used to do simple `sed`-like `s/search/replace/` operations on filenames.

```
rename -n 's/^file(\d+)\.txt$/sprintf "file%03i.txt", $1/e' file*.txt
```

The `/e` regex modifier tells rename to treat the replacement portion of the s/search/replace/ operator as executable perl code.  The `sprintf` function is used to zero-pad the digits before the .txt extension.

or it can be generalised to work with any filename prefix and extension - e.g.

```
rename -n 's/\A(.*?)(\d+)(\..*)\z/sprintf "%s%03i%s", $1, $2, $3/esm' *
```

The `/s` and `/m` regex modifiers are used to ensure that the script works with any filename, even those containing newlines.  `\A` is the beginning-of-string anchor and `\z` is the end-of-string anchor.

Note that the `-n` option makes it a dry run, so it will only show what it would do without actually renaming any files. Remove the `-n`, or replace it with `-v` for verbose output, when you've confirmed that it does what you want.